# Page numbering from a macro

Tags: header-footer, environments

I am trying to modify a thesis template from another university (mine does not provide a latex thesis template).  The original puts Roman numeral page numbers at the bottom in the center, I need to move them to the top right.

```
\newenvironment{frontmatter}{
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  }
  {\newpage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}\setcounter{page}{1}}
```

I have tried using the \pagestyle{fancy} option and manually specifying the header I want. This causes the page numbers to appear at both the top and the bottom

```
  \newenvironment{frontmatter}{
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
  \rhead{\thepage}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  }
  {\newpage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}\setcounter{page}{1}}
```

Does anyone know how I can change this environment so that the page number appear in the top right?

Thank You, I appreciate any assistance!

I am only interested in solutions that allow me to do this by editing this environment.

Comment: Doing `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}` is useless, because the setting will be immediately forgotten: an environment forms a group. Nonetheless, `\setcounter{page}{1}` is not forgotten, because `\setcounter` always adds globally, contrary to `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand`. It would be better style to use `\clearpage` rather than `\newpage`.

Answer (score 2):

When specifying `\pagestyle{fancy}`, there are some defaults at play here. One of them is the placement of the page number in the footer. So, by issuing `\rhead{..}` you're *adding* to the existing page style elements and only changing the `r`ight `head`er. You'll have to clear the footer - `\fancyfoot{}` (and header - `\fancyhead{}`, maybe), just so you start off from scratch. Header and footer clearing can be done simultaneously using `\fancyhf{}`.

```
\newenvironment{frontmatter}{%
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}% Page counter representation
  \pagestyle{fancy}% Set page style to fancy
  \fancyhf{}% Clear fancy header & footer
  \rhead{\thepage}% Right header
}{%
  \newpage
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I really appreciate it that fixes it!